Evaluating $\int_0^1\frac{\log(2-x^s)}{1-x} dx$
I was initially trying to solve this nice looking integral from @calculusmerchant on Instagram:
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\ln(\sin x+\cos x)}{\sin x}dx$$
https://www.instagram.com/p/C_sxyxxtUWJ/
However, after using Weierstrass substitution I get two integrals, one that equals $\frac{\pi^2}{24}$, but the other one looks a bit more challenging.
It is the one below :
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(2-x^2)}{1-x} dx$$
And as it converges inside the bounds of integration, we can generalize it where for $s=1$ we get $\frac{\pi^2}{12}$ but I can't find any way to solve it afterward:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(2-x^s)}{1-x} dx$$

integral-calculator.com gives you a step by step derivation of a solution to the second integral in terms of dilogarithms.

For $s=3$ you would face derivatives of nasty generalized hypergeometric function.

Here is an alternative, perhaps more effective, evaluation of the original integral
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\ln(\sin x+\cos x)}{\sin x}dx\\
=&\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos t \cos x}{1+\sin t \sin 2x}dt\ dx\\
=& \int_0^{\pi/2} {\sqrt{\csc t-1}\ \text{arccoth}\sqrt{\csc t+1}}
\ dt \\
 =& \ \text{arccoth}^2\sqrt{\csc t+1}\bigg|_0^{\pi/2} 
=  \text{arccoth}^2\sqrt{2}
\end{align}

You can actually solve your original integral with the $x^2$.
$$\int_0^1\frac{\log(2-x^2)}{1-x}dx=-\int_0^1\frac{\log(2-x^2)}{x-1}dx$$
Substituting $u=x-1$
$$\int\frac{\ln[2-(u+1)^2]}{u}du$$
Which can be expanded to:
$$I=\int\frac{\ln(u+\sqrt{2}+1)}{u}du+\int\frac{\ln(u-\sqrt{2}+1)}{u}du+\ln(-1)\int\frac1udu$$
Now we evaluate each separately. Take $I=I_1+I_2+I_3$ for clarity.
It would take ages for me to type out every single operation, so I'll just run through the steps in words. If you need any clarification please leave a comment and I'd be happy to help.
Beginning with $I_1$,
$$I_1=\int\frac{\ln(u+\sqrt{2}+1)}{u}du$$
We will perform some substitutions and eventually arrive at the following:
$$\int-\frac{\ln(1-v)}{v}dv$$
This is a special integral known as the dilogarithm denoted Li$_2(v)$. After substituting this we solve $I_1$.
$$I_1=\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)\ln(u)-\text{Li}_2\left( -\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}+1} \right)$$
We will solve $I_2$ which is nearly identical. The only difference will be a couple of sign changes.
$$I_2=\int\frac{\ln(u-\sqrt{2}+1)}{u}du=\ln(1-\sqrt{2})\ln(u)-\text{Li}_2\left( -\frac{u}{1-\sqrt{2}} \right)$$
Finally, we know $I_3$ is simply $\ln u$ from our first calculus class. We will now plug in $I_n$ to write our full solution of $I$:
$$I=-\text{Li}_2\left( -\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}+1} \right)-\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{u}{1-\sqrt{2}} \right)+\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)\ln(u)+\ln(1-\sqrt{2})\ln(u)+\ln(-1)\ln(u)$$
We now need to substitute $x-1$ for each $u$:
$$I=-\text{Li}_2\left( -\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{2}+1} \right)-\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{x-1}{1-\sqrt{2}} \right)+\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)\ln(x-1)+\ln(1-\sqrt{2})\ln(x-1)+\ln(-1)\ln(x-1)$$
Now we simplify to get our final answer:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\log(2-x^2)}{1-x}dx=$$
$$\color{blue}{\operatorname{Li}_{2}\left(\left(\sqrt{2} + 1\right) \left(x - 1\right)\right) + \operatorname{Li}_{2}\left(-\left(\sqrt{2} - 1\right) \left(x - 1\right)\right) + \left(-\ln\left(\sqrt{2} + 1\right) - \ln\left(1 - \sqrt{2}\right) - \ln\left(-1\right)\right) \ln\left(\left|x - 1\right|\right)}$$

How can your final answer have $x$ (the integration variable) in it?

@JohnBarber Great point, my answer has $x$ because I only found the indefinite integral. I did not include the answer once evaluated from $0$ to $1$, which I will edit my answer to include.
